# Chaining RxJS map operators and ngrx effects Issue

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

My app uses ngrx and ngrx effects. Here is one of my app effects:

```
  @Effect()
  reloadPersonalInfo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.RELOAD_PERSONAL_INFO)
    .filter(() => <boolean>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticated')))
    .switchMap(() =>
      this.userAccountService
        .retrieveCurrentUserAccount()
        .map(currentUserAccount => new LoadUserAccountAction(currentUserAccount))
        .map(() => new SigninAction())
    );
```

I am wondering why the `LoadUserAccountAction` does not enter my reducer function except if I comment out `//.map(() => new SigninAction())`

Can anyone please help? What I am getting wrong?

Comment: Effects are meant to only return one action.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for your comment and the edit. Can you please suggest a way to change the design of the app in order to avoid returning several actions from on effect?

Comment: You are trying to return both "LoadUserAccountAction" and "SigninAction" in one effect. You should return one of the other. In other words, remove one of your .map lines in the code.

Comment: I was referring to cartant's reply. Does you comment about returning only one action also apply to returning several actions "concatenated" with `concatMap`(see reply below)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `LoadUserAccountAction` is not dispatched because it's not emitted by the effect, as the final `.map(() => new SigninAction())` is seeing the `SigninAction` emitted instead.

It is possible to emit multiple actions from an effect, you'd just need to do it like this:

```js
@Effect()
reloadPersonalInfo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.RELOAD_PERSONAL_INFO)
  .filter(() => <boolean>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticated')))
  .switchMap(() => this.userAccountService
    .retrieveCurrentUserAccount()
    .concatMap(currentUserAccount => [
      new LoadUserAccountAction(currentUserAccount),
      new SigninAction()
    ])
  );
```

The `concatMap` operator will flatten the array that contains the two actions so that both actions are emitted - in the order in which they are declared in the array.